# Xilinx SDK 2018.3 Linker error although libraries exist, "undefined reference"

Tags: c++, ubuntu, linker, eclipse-cdt, xilinx

### The situation

I am following the course "[Introduction to Deep Learning with Xilinx SoCs Technical Training Course](https://www.hackster.io/workshops/ultra96-ai-course)" for the Ultra96v2 board and reached Lab No. 5.

### The error message

I am able to follow along until I am supposed to build the project in the SDK. It seems to compile fine but then fails and throws errors like these:

```
16:50:21 **** Auto Build of configuration Debug for project mnist_live_io ****
make all 
Building target: mnist_live_io.elf
Invoking: ARM v8 Linux g++ linker
aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ -L/tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib --sysroot=/media/user/6b04b610-ff80-4702-a575-b0b1a78fbafb/training/AvnetTTC/DPU/U96AI_student_20200115/U96AI/2018_3/work/lab2/sdk/sysroots/aarch64-xilinx-linux -o "mnist_live_io.elf"  ./src/mnist_live_io.o   -ldputils -ln2cube -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_videoio -lpthread
/tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libopencv_core.so when searching for -lopencv_core
/tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libopencv_core.a when searching for -lopencv_core
/tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libopencv_core.so when searching for -lopencv_core
/tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libopencv_core.a when searching for -lopencv_core
/tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libopencv_highgui.so when searching for -lopencv_highgui
/tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libopencv_highgui.a when searching for -lopencv_highgui
makefile:48: recipe for target 'mnist_live_io.elf' failed
/tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libopencv_highgui.so when searching for -lopencv_highgui
/tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libopencv_highgui.a when searching for -lopencv_highgui
/tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so when searching for -lopencv_imgproc
/tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libopencv_imgproc.a when searching for -lopencv_imgproc
/tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so when searching for -lopencv_imgproc
/tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libopencv_imgproc.a when searching for -lopencv_imgproc
./src/mnist_live_io.o: In function `runMNIST(dpu_task*, cv::Mat&)':
/media/user/6b04b610-ff80-4702-a575-b0b1a78fbafb/training/AvnetTTC/DPU/U96AI_student_20200115/U96AI/2018_3/work/lab5/workspace/mnist_live_io/Debug/../src/mnist_live_io.cc:139: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
/media/user/6b04b610-ff80-4702-a575-b0b1a78fbafb/training/AvnetTTC/DPU/U96AI_student_20200115/U96AI/2018_3/work/lab5/workspace/mnist_live_io/Debug/../src/mnist_live_io.cc:139: undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
/media/user/6b04b610-ff80-4702-a575-b0b1a78fbafb/training/AvnetTTC/DPU/U96AI_student_20200115/U96AI/2018_3/work/lab5/workspace/mnist_live_io/Debug/../src/mnist_live_io.cc:141: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
/media/user/6b04b610-ff80-4702-a575-b0b1a78fbafb/training/AvnetTTC/DPU/U96AI_student_20200115/U96AI/2018_3/work/lab5/workspace/mnist_live_io/Debug/../src/mnist_live_io.cc:141: undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
/media/user/6b04b610-ff80-4702-a575-b0b1a78fbafb/training/AvnetTTC/DPU/U96AI_student_20200115/U96AI/2018_3/work/lab5/workspace/mnist_live_io/Debug/../src/mnist_live_io.cc:142: undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
/media/user/6b04b610-ff80-4702-a575-b0b1a78fbafb/training/AvnetTTC/DPU/U96AI_student_20200115/U96AI/2018_3/work/lab5/workspace/mnist_live_io/Debug/../src/mnist_live_io.cc:143: undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
/media/user/6b04b610-ff80-4702-a575-b0b1a78fbafb/training/AvnetTTC/DPU/U96AI_student_20200115/U96AI/2018_3/work/lab5/workspace/mnist_live_io/Debug/../src/mnist_live_io.cc:143: undefined reference to `cv::findContours(cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int, cv::Point_<int>)'
/media/user/6b04b610-ff80-4702-a575-b0b1a78fbafb/training/AvnetTTC/DPU/U96AI_student_20200115/U96AI/2018_3/work/lab5/workspace/mnist_live_io/Debug/../src/mnist_live_io.cc:147: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
/media/user/6b04b610-ff80-4702-a575-b0b1a78fbafb/training/AvnetTTC/DPU/U96AI_student_20200115/U96AI/2018_3/work/lab5/workspace/mnist_live_io/Debug/../src/mnist_live_io.cc:147: undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
/media/user/6b04b610-ff80-4702-a575-b0b1a78fbafb/training/AvnetTTC/DPU/U96AI_student_20200115/U96AI/2018_3/work/lab5/workspace/mnist_live_io/Debug/../src/mnist_live_io.cc:172: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
/media/user/6b04b610-ff80-4702-a575-b0b1a78fbafb/training/AvnetTTC/DPU/U96AI_student_20200115/U96AI/2018_3/work/lab5/workspace/mnist_live_io/Debug/../src/mnist_live_io.cc:172: undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
/media/user/6b04b610-ff80-4702-a575-b0b1a78fbafb/training/AvnetTTC/DPU/U96AI_student_20200115/U96AI/2018_3/work/lab5/workspace/mnist_live_io/Debug/../src/mnist_live_io.cc:183: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
/media/user/6b04b610-ff80-4702-a575-b0b1a78fbafb/training/AvnetTTC/DPU/U96AI_student_20200115/U96AI/2018_3/work/lab5/workspace/mnist_live_io/Debug/../src/mnist_live_io.cc:183: undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
/media/user/6b04b610-ff80-4702-a575-b0b1a78fbafb/training/AvnetTTC/DPU/U96AI_student_20200115/U96AI/2018_3/work/lab5/workspace/mnist_live_io/Debug/../src/mnist_live_io.cc:219: undefined reference to `cv::putText(cv::Mat&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, double, cv::Scalar_<double>, int, int, bool)'
./src/mnist_live_io.o: In function `digitRecognition(dpu_kernel*)::{lambda()#3}::operator()() const':
/media/user/6b04b610-ff80-4702-a575-b0b1a78fbafb/training/AvnetTTC/DPU/U96AI_student_20200115/U96AI/2018_3/work/lab5/workspace/mnist_live_io/Debug/../src/mnist_live_io.cc:354: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
/media/user/6b04b610-ff80-4702-a575-b0b1a78fbafb/training/AvnetTTC/DPU/U96AI_student_20200115/U96AI/2018_3/work/lab5/workspace/mnist_live_io/Debug/../src/mnist_live_io.cc:354: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
./src/mnist_live_io.o: In function `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray<cv::Point_<int> >(std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > > >&)':
/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1145: undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_OutputArray'
/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1145: undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_OutputArray'
./src/mnist_live_io.o: In function `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray<cv::Vec<int, 4> >(std::vector<cv::Vec<int, 4>, std::allocator<cv::Vec<int, 4> > >&)':
/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1143: undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_OutputArray'
/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1143: undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_OutputArray'
./src/mnist_live_io.o: In function `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray<cv::Point_<int> >(std::vector<cv::Point_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > const&)':
/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1122: undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1122: undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
./src/mnist_live_io.o: In function `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray<cv::Point_<int> >(std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > > > const&)':
/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1125: undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1125: undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
./src/mnist_live_io.o: In function `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray<cv::Vec<int, 4> >(std::vector<cv::Vec<int, 4>, std::allocator<cv::Vec<int, 4> > > const&)':
/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1122: undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
./src/mnist_live_io.o:/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1122: more undefined references to `vtable for cv::_InputArray' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mnist_live_io.elf] Error 1

16:50:22 Build Finished (took 615ms)
```

It looks like it's a linker issue. The OpenCV libaries in question are all installed and the includes also are as required. With lines like

```
/mnist_live_io.cc:183: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
```

the Xilinx SDK tells me that it won't find a definition for objects and so on, although the libraries are provided.

---

### Correct invocation of the linker

As you can see,

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ -L/tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib --sysroot=/media/user/6b04b610-ff80-4702-a575-b0b1a78fbafb/training/AvnetTTC/DPU/U96AI_student_20200115/U96AI/2018_3/work/lab2/sdk/sysroots/aarch64-xilinx-linux -o "mnist_live_io.elf"  ./src/mnist_live_io.o   -ldputils -ln2cube -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_videoio -lpthread
```

tells me that the linker is initialized correctly with the needed libraries. And it seems as if the linker finds all of them, otherwise it would throw a different error.

---

### Skipping incompatible libraries

The lines like

```
/tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libopencv_core.so when searching for -lopencv_core
```

started to appear once I started to define a library include path to the OpenCV libraries I installed. So it looks like it finds all libraries already on its own, but won't link the header and sources correctly.

---

### Libraries are installed correctly

The command `/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep opencv` returns:

```
    libopencv_videostab.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.so.2.4
    libopencv_videostab.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.so
    libopencv_video.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.so.2.4
    libopencv_video.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.so
    libopencv_ts.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ts.so.2.4
    libopencv_ts.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ts.so
    libopencv_superres.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_superres.so.2.4
    libopencv_superres.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_superres.so
    libopencv_stitching.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stitching.so.2.4
    libopencv_stitching.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stitching.so
    libopencv_photo.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.so.2.4
    libopencv_photo.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.so
    libopencv_ocl.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ocl.so.2.4
    libopencv_ocl.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ocl.so
    libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4
    libopencv_objdetect.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.so
    libopencv_ml.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ml.so.2.4
    libopencv_ml.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ml.so
    libopencv_legacy.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_legacy.so.2.4
    libopencv_legacy.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_legacy.so
    libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4
    libopencv_imgproc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so
    libopencv_highgui.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4
    libopencv_highgui.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so
    libopencv_gpu.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_gpu.so.2.4
    libopencv_gpu.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_gpu.so
    libopencv_flann.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so.2.4
    libopencv_flann.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so
    libopencv_features2d.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.so.2.4
    libopencv_features2d.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.so
    libopencv_core.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.2.4
    libopencv_core.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so
    libopencv_contrib.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_contrib.so.2.4
    libopencv_contrib.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_contrib.so
    libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4
    libopencv_calib3d.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so
```

so the libraries are installed. Though when I want to specify the path to those libraries, which should be the ones the Xilinx SDK requires, it throws error lines like the ones above mentioned ("skipping incompatible ...").

---

### Tried solutions

- I already tried reinstalling by various methods. It didn't help anything. It should usually work right out of the box since the tutorial doesn't mention any additional steps which I haven't taken already.
- I also tried to fiddle with the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, though that didn't help in any way (tried specifying more paths, tried unsetting it, etc.).
- As mentioned I tried to specify an explicit path to the installed libraries, but that just kicked off more error messages.

What is happening here? This is like either:

1. Some steps are missing when following the tutorial

or

2. The Xilinx SDK has a big bug which is not fixed, rendering it useless.

---

**Does anyone have experience with this issue(s)?** I really need to fix this, because otherwise I won't be able to create software for my Ultra96 board, which would be a pity since I would like to use Xilinx' products.

**If you need any additional information, please just ask!**

Comment: You are trying to link ARM libraries with your x86-64 project.  Those are different CPU architectures.

Comment: @DrewDormann Okay fail, thank you, that makes sense. It explains why the "skipping incompatible" errors pop up. However, without explicitly specifying those x86-64 libs, the SDK seems to detect the correct libraries, but just won't link them.

Comment: Also, where would I get ARM libraries from for program, if I really needed them? Are there ARM OpenCV libs available?